I have 3 jobs listed as idle on Run:AI, but none of these jobs are listed as the list of current job current. How is that possible?
I have 3 jobs listed as idle on Run:AI, but none of these jobs are listed as the list of current jobs. How is that possible? I can still connect to the jobs, so they are still running.

Screenshot 1: 3 idle jobs:

Screenshot 2: None of these jobs are listed as the list of current jobs:

In the list of current jobs (Screenshot 2), I used the same user name in the search box as in the user name displayed in the user column in the list of idle jobs  (Screenshot 1).
